# Iterate through a MongoDB object's data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I will start off with how my mongoDB data looks like:

```
_id : 5c5b450918cb2b121648ff7a
name : "dannondarko"
email : "dangilmail@gmail.com"
password : "$2a$10$3z5m1e9Pcfid72Q2GchCjeTD55/SsIxmtWr3I1ZiA.DX/KlpfTbdK"
date : 2019-02-06 20:35:21.973
__v : 0
posts : Array
    0 : Object
        note : "test for the user dannondarko"
        date : "02/08/2019"
```

This is just a side project and most likely will never be live so don't worry about the security of me posting this data! As for how I am procession the code in my server code:

```
app.get('/:username', (req, res) => {
  username = req.params.username.toLowerCase();
  const collection = req.app.locals.collection;

  collection.find({ name: username }).toArray(function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send("Error communicating with the DB.");
    } else if (results.length > 0) {
      console.log("Here are the results: " + results);
      console.log({people: results});
      res.status(200).render('profile', {posts: results, name: username});
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
});
```

What I am doing with this code is say you head to the address bar '/dannondarko', it should find 'dannondarko' in the collection, which it does fine, and then the 'results' variable is the complete object that I posted above. What I am trying to do is just get the 'posts' data, such as the note and date.

The note and date is the only data I need, which will be sent to this .ejs file that should create a post (kind of like FB) that shows the users' notes and date of the post. Here is my .ejs file:

```
<h1 class="mt-4"><%= name %></h1>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <% for(var i=0; i < posts.length; i++) { %>
      <div class="container">
          <label><%= posts[i].note %></label>
        <div class="container">
          <label><%=  posts[i].date %></label>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

I hope that's enough information. I believe my downfall is not knowing how to just extract the 'posts' array from MongoDB from a certain user and iterate through the objects and sending over the note and date to the .ejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `results` is an array of documents and you render this array to ejs as `posts`. Now in your ejs file `posts` represent the array of documents, not the `posts` array. So if you want to loop through all results you should edit your code like this:

```
<% posts.forEach(post =>  { %>
<h1 class="mt-4"><%= post.name %></h1>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <% post.posts.forEach(p =>  { %>
      <div class="container">
          <label><%= p.note %></label>
        <div class="container">
          <label><%=  p.date %></label>
        </div>
      </div>
  <% }) %>
</div>
<% }) %>
```

If i understand well your mongo model structure the above should help you.

Comment: Wow, man! Thank you a lot. That makes a lot of sense. I really should have known that but I definitely  appreciate it brother. And just so you know, there is a missing closing parenthesis right about the last </div> after the closing brace.

Comment: Happy that i helped you man, i fixed the missing parenthesis.